# TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable при создании суперюзера

Tags: python, django

после заполнения формы для создания суперюзера получаю следуюющее:

```
   Superuser created successfully.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

пофиксить не получается

Comment: Код в студию! (Кстати, суперюзер у Вас создался успешно). Судя по строке с ошибкой, `database_name` в Вашем случае не является строкой, а имеет тип `PosixPath`. Уточните, как из этого типа получить строковое представление. В любом случае **нужен Ваш код в вопросе**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникла по причине того, что Вы пытались применить оператор `in` к объекту, не являющемуся итерируемым. Видимо, Вы ожидали, что `database_name` должно быть строкой, что логично. Однако, судя по тексту ошибки, это не так. Объект `database_name` имеет тип `PosixPath` и, следовательно, с ним нельзя работать, как с обычной строкой. Однако, проведя пару экспериментов, я выяснил, что данный тип легко преобразуется к строке, например, следующим образом:

```python
str(database_name)
```

Таким образом, чтобы всё заработало, Ваша строка должна принять вид:

```python
return str(database_name) == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in str(database_name)
```

А вообще, советую прочитать про `pathlib`, частью которой является тип `PosixPath`, например, [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). У этих объектов есть ряд полезных методов, могут пригодиться.

**UPD**: так как по новым данным выяснилось, что этот файл read only, воспользовавшись Google, оставлю здесь краткое содержание того, что ответили на данный вопрос наши коллеги с "большого" SO [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64046773/11790859), [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64185724/11790859) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64634674/11790859).

Итак, судя по ответам, существует некий файл, где задаётся имя БД. Выглядит это примерно так:

```python
'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
```

чтобы решить проблему, следует явно привести значение к типу `str` следующим образом:

```python
'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
```

либо воспользоваться возможностями модуля `os`:

```python
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
```

Comment: файл, на который ругается, я не редактировала и отредактировать его не могу. 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable

от толко для чтения

Comment: @Julia, снова гуглить учить... Итак, небольшая справка о том, как просить помощи у гугла: берём Вашу ошибку (её последнюю строчку, где написано, что не так), копипастим в Google. Туда же добавляем, где возникла эта ошибка (что-то типа "Django sqlite3"). Нажимаем Enter и вуаля, первые три результата – три вопроса на "большом" SO, в **каждом** из которых поднимается Ваша проблема и **есть ответ**. Так уж и быть, проделал за Вас: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64046773/11790859, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64185724/11790859, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64634674/11790859.